# wordpress custom post type with custom slug and get variables

Tags: wordpress, url, archive, custom-post-type, slug

I've defined a custom post type in wordpress in this way:

```
add_action('init', 'register_cima_fellowship');

function register_cima_fellowship() {
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position'=>20,
        'show_ui'=>true,
        'show_in_menu'=>true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fellow'),    
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'=>true
    );
    register_post_type('cima_fellowship', $args);
}
```

I've created a custom archive in a file called `archive-cima_fellowship.php` and it works, showing all my cpt.

This cpt have a meta attribute like status, to define some of them as current and other as past. I would like to have two different archive pages, one to show only he current and another to show only the past.

For now I turn around this using a get variable in this way `mysite.com/cima_fellowship/?type=past`

But I would like to have cleaner url like `mysite.com/fellows/past`.

For this I defined `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fellow'),` in the registration of the cpt, but I can't access the archive page trough `` `mysite.com/fellows ``, I still have to visit 'mysite.com/cima_fellowship/', and I can't find out how to "style" the URL.

Any suggestion? tutorial? guide?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Now I am not 100% sure if this will work but try adding:

```
'has_archive' => 'fellow'
```

So you would have:

```
 function register_cima_fellowship() {
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position'=>20,
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'show_in_menu'=>true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'has_archive'=>true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fellow', 'with_front' => false),    
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail'),

);
register_post_type('cima_fellowship', $args);
}
```

I had a similar problem 10 or so months ago and I add this and seemed to fix my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you that by adding that line I would access the archive page like `mysite.com/fellow/` ? Unluckly it is not working...

Comment: Do you have access to your htaccess file? there maybe something outlying in there that is cause you problems. From what I know your original code should work without a work around.

Comment: Try the code above again, I have changed it back to the original code with the addition of " 'with_front' => false " to your rewrite array. Again I can't say it will fix your problem but worth a try, other users on wp forums have had success with it some haven't

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with WordPress, so long as you have the 'slug' => 'my-slug' argument it will work but you have to first change your permalink structure. Change your permalinks via WorkPress>Settings>Permalinks to a random different structure then back to your previous one.

This should fix the issue.